# how to make heritance in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i'm trying to developp an application that manages a set off books(library).
i'm using hibernate ti generate the relationnel database.
i have these classes :User, Adherent, Admin

```
@entity
@Table(name="users")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE_USER",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorTyp)

class User{
@Id
private int UserId;
private String name;
private String email

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ADH")
public class Adherent extends User{

    private int solde;
    private int penalised;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="adherent")
    private List<Ouvrage> ouvrages;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ouvrages")
public class Ouvrage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idOuvrage;
    private String ISBN;
    private String Titre;
    private boolean reservable;
    private boolean dispo;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="proprietaire")
    private Adherent proprietaire;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="ouvrage")
    private Emprunt emrunt;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ADM")
public class Admin extends User{
    private String notifications;
    private String messages;

}
```

and when i test i get this error

> @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on dao.entities.Emprunt.adherent references an unknown entity: dao.entities.Adherent

Comment: so you have some field Emprunt.adherent and you don't bother posting that class. WTF?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define

```
@JoinColumn(name="proprietaire")
private Adherent proprietaire;
```

as a standard User

```
@JoinColumn(name="proprietaire")
private User proprietaire;
```

the real type will be always Adherent if the data present on database are not corrupted and if you set it always as an Adherent type.

Comment: i get this erroe after doing that: Unknown entity: dao.entities.Adherent

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i fixed  th issue, i have imorted hibernate.annotation instead of java.persistance in my adherent entity